# JetBrains IDEA download sources for ivy project

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy, nutch

i have project with ivy (Apache Nutch), can i automatically download sources code for it's dependencies with Jetbrains IDEA?

Comment: Maven Central stores built binaries and most Open source projects also include source code. See: http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.nutch%22%20AND%20a%3A%22nutch%22

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ivy / Artifactory Getting a jar and its sources and javadoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260570/ivy-artifactory-getting-a-jar-and-its-sources-and-javadoc)