# Selecting optional dependencies of OSGi-bundles with Ivy

Tags: ant, osgi, ivy

I use Ivy to resolve OSGi bundles, like `org.eclipse.jdt`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="bundle" name="org.eclipse.jdt" rev="x.y.z"/>
</dependencies>
```

It works fine and gives me all mandatory dependencies.

My question is, how can I select some (not all) optional dependencies of transitive bundles?

I can:

- Select optional dependencies of `org.eclipse.jdt` by activating `use_xxx` configuration
- Select all optional dependencies using `transitive-optional` configuration

What I actually need is a possibility to globally activate a configuration `use_yyy`. Globally means (applying to all transitive dependencies):

- If a module doesn't have this configuration, do nothing
- If a module does have this configuration, activate it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ivy: Fetching Javadocs and Sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304976/ivy-fetching-javadocs-and-sources)